# PowerShell match first occurence of string only

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to match the first occurence of a string using PowerShell:

```
$virtualMachine1 = "002DC001"
$virtualMachine2 = "003SP002"

$virtualMachine1 -match "002"
True
```

Good

```
$virtualMachine2 -match "002"
True
```

Bad.

Is there a way to match *only* the first `002` in the string? I think regex is required but I am stuck.

Comment: You mean *starting* with that string? Because that's the first occurrence...

Comment: Use `-match "^002"`